# How to tighten big wires into circuit breaker holes?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker

I am installing this. After tightening the screw hardly, the big wire still falls out if I pull it a little bit with very small force. I am not sure that I am doing like others would do. Do you have any idea to tighten the wire into that hole? The wire is 105C - 600V, the circuit breaker is 63A

[image]

Comment: You are putting the wire inside the clamping part ?

Comment: @SolarMike do you have picture of clamping part?

Comment: Well, you are best placed to take a picture of the device you have... I suggest that you turn the clamping screw and watch the clamp to see how it operates.

Comment: yeah, I put the wire deeply into that hole in the picture as deep as possible, then I use a screwdriver to drive a screw from a hole above (you can see clearly 4 holes in my picture where I put the screwdriver in). As I do it, the clamp is rised up and the wire get tightened.

Comment: You say that the circuit breaker is rated at 63A. Can you share what guage the red wire is?

Comment: Yes, what gauge is the red wire?

Comment: Did you fully open the clamp by turning the screw counter clockwise until ir stopped then insert screw under the plate and tighten CW until it is properly torqued? I usually back off and re torque 3 times to allow large wires to relax  and clamp better.

Comment: @MichaelKaras the red wire is  Awg-6, the circuit breaker is A9F74463

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the red wire is Awg-6, the circuit breaker is A9F74463

Comment: @EdBeal yes, I did. But after doing all that, the red wire is easly fall out if I pull it out with a very small pull force.

Comment: @Dat -  It is quite possible that the clamp on the circuit breaker is made for a larger diameter wire. Your 6AWG wire, in particular due to it being stranded, may just be too small to clamp in that breaker.

Comment: If I have issues after torquing 3 times I will flex the wire up and down and re torque. Flexing the wires is usually not needed with wires below 1/0. Larger stranded wires need 3 torque relax retorque   Over 250 I always flex this gets the wires packed into the spaces and retorque. Other than that the screw or nut may have partially stripped.  I would verify the lug and screw are still good.

Comment: Can you orient it so the sun is shining down the wire holes, and then shoot us a photo looking down into the wire holes?  It would help to understand what the mechanism looks like in there.

Answer (score 4):

No guessing is allowed.

The breaker's labeling or specification sheet will call out a specific torque you must use.  Torque it to that spec.  And no other.  If you lack the equipment to do so, get it.

I would say look closely inside there while you turn the screw on an empty one, so you have a clear understanding of how the mechanism works.  The wire flaring out like that suggests it may be missing the mechanism.

Also, as Programmer66 suggests, make sure that particular hole isn't broken; try another hole.

Comment: I know that there are torque specs, and obviously it is wise to follow them. But I never met an electrician who would ever do that for a 63 A circuit breaker. Very, very few electricians (at least in Denmark) even have a torque wrench. When I was in a electrical board production facility, we never used a torque wrench for anything this size. When we worked with larger currents, starting from a few hundred amps, we would use torque wrenches.

Comment: This is why I specified residential, commercial and even setting the transformers and meters outside of residences, I would imagine the torque would need to be set, even the main coming into the panel inside the house...  but after that since I was a supervisor overseeing the construction, never witnessed a torque wrench used. That said, the specs are set for a reason, and from a legal respect for the most part, a torque wrench should be used, since a DIY'er may not know what "snug and a little more" may mean.

Comment: "But I never met an electrician who would ever do that" @MadsSkjern ... and so it was in America until they took a test rig to trade shows and found out [how really, really awful people were at this](https://www.ecmweb.com/construction/article/20890860/do-you-have-a-calibrated-arm).  And being an electrician didn't make you any better at it; Jane in the billing department was setting torques with equal ... skill.  That started the rumbling that became a Code thing and now everybody has to own a torque screwdriver, and inspectors inspect for it.

Answer (score 3):

That I am aware of, it is not to be tightened gently, it needs to be tightened rather snugly, typically there is a torque rating that is given, that will be on the breaker itself, if not on the makers website.

If you are certain that the wire is stripped bare to the correct length, and inserted into the correct spot, and tightened, the wire will not easily pull out, if at all.

Comment: And I'll stress that to do this properly, you need a torque driver. Too little torque and the wire will pull out.  Too much and you will (at best) just squish the wires or (worse) split the circuit breaker and ruin it.

Comment: Try inserting the wire into one of the other holes and check and see if it has the same issue.  The hole you are using may be defected.

Comment: The main clue for me was in the question the " After tightening the screw hardly, " and "(very gently)"

Comment: I asked a master electrician the question how tight do I make it, he said, get it snug, then go a little more. FWIW, in residential electrics, I have never seen an electrician use a torque setting on a given tool.

Comment: Aside from the SF Bay Area: almost all of our electrical inspections include a torque test these days. This started about a year ago and has spread through adjacent jurisdictions. Most require the electrician present. I have the impression there was a high profile fire locally in the last few years that prompted a bit of CYA behavior.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate -- yeah, I suspect that the folks who are going with the program re: torque inspection are going to get pleasantly surprised by *not* getting callbacks 20-30 years down the line because some lug burned up XD

Comment: @Jack I am sure that I do it all correct. after tightening, when I touch the the red wire, it seems to be very hard to pull out, it feels snug. But if I pull it out with a very small force, it pull out easily.

Answer (score 2):

That appears to be a rising clamp wire attachment, with these you must fully loosen the screw before inserting the wire, else you risk the wire passing below the clamp jaw and not being connected, or worse only some of the wire strands being clamped and the join overheating.

After insering the wire tighten the screw to the correct torque,

Comment: yes I fully loosen the screw, all the wire strands being clamped

Comment: Please try another hole and see if it is still failing to secure the wire.